# CodeIgniter 3.0 insert_batch works localhost but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a customer model with the following function:

```
public function add($data)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('customers', $data);
}
```

Using this function in localhost on a 5.6 php environment works without any problem. On server with 7.0 php environment I receive the error:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1549</p>

<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
<p>Error Number: 1136</p><p>Column count doesn't match value count at row 1</p><p>INSERT INTO `customers` () VALUES ('John Doe', '25', 'Male'), ('Brad Doe', '22', 'Male')</p><p>Filename: models/Customers_model.php</p><p>Line Number: 22</p>
```

Well, I dunno why the final query has no column names, since my `$data` content is perfect.

```
public function add($data)
{
    print_r($data);
    $this->db->insert_batch('customers', $data);
}
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'John Doe'
            [age] => 25
            [sex] => 'Male'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'Brad Doe'
            [age] => 22
            [sex] => 'Male'
        )
)
```

And finally my server configuration on Cpanel
[image]

Comment: can you please add function of controller in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the culprit.  It happened to me when I was testing on PHP 7.0.0 (for some reason) as well today:

bcit-ci/CodeIgniter Issue #4804: [error insert_batch using PHP7](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4804)

Looks like the maintainer used reset() instead of the original current() to grab the first element. This [Snippet](https://3v4l.org/9M2dD) is an example a contributor provided to show the difference.

Comment: I happen to saw that link after a while. Although it worked, I end up using the 5.6 version of PHP in my server environment because I was getting too many issues/warnings with some libraries.

Comment: I think when they release the fix it will be fine.  Thanks