# insert_batch works live server; my server; but not on raspberry

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've installed PHP7.1 in my raspberry and copy the project folder from my personal computer to the raspberry.

My whole project works fine in raspberry, except when I use the function `insert_batch`.

The same code is working on my online server without any problem and in my personal computer. With that said, my only conclusion is that some libraries/dependencies might be missing?

This is what I'm trying to insert:
`Array[0] = array('field_1' => 'value_field_1', 'field_2' => 'value_field_2');`

And I'm getting the error:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1520</p>
```

Now, I won't go edit the core of the framework, because since it's working on other computers it must be a config issue.

To make it clear: my live server works and uses linux; my personal computer works and it's windows with Xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues months ago and I didn't remember.

**Solved**.

[CodeIgniter 3.0 insert_batch works localhost but not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475400/codeigniter-3-0-insert-batch-works-localhost-but-not-on-server)